# jQuery structure, object and normal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made two quick different jQuery structures, one is an object structure, one is just a normal. I'd like to know why some people choose the first one, looks like it is more coded. what is the advantage beteween these two? Thanks

HTML

```
<div id="slide">
    <button>Click here</button>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime dolor dicta eligendi optio officia earum qui vitae voluptatum at ullam consequuntur recusandae quisquam accusantium consequatur iure quae vel quasi eveniet libero modi aspernatur officiis reprehenderit rem quo totam ea voluptas?</p>
</div>
```

jQuery 1

```
(function(){
    var slide = {
        wrap: $('#slide'),
        button: $('#slide').find('button'),

        init: function(){
            slide.button.on('click', this.show);
        },
        show: function(){
            slide.wrap.find('p').slideToggle();
        }
    }
    slide.init();
})();
```

jQuery 2

```
$(function() {
  var wrap = $('#slide'),
      button = wrap.find('button');
  button.on('click', function(){
    wrap.find('p').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the object literal is indeed nothing more but superflous. However, think of

```
function Slide(selector) {
   var slide = {
        wrap: $(selector),
        button: $(selector).find('button'),

        init: function(){
            slide.button.on('click', this.show);
        },
        show: function(){
            slide.wrap.find('p').slideToggle();
        }
    }
    return slide;
}
```

Now, by executing `Slide()` you get an *object* back, with which you can do various things:

```
$(function() {
    var slide1 = Slide('#slide');
    slide1.init();
});
```

In this example, calling its `.init()` function. As modules get larger, you *need* objects to expose various methods as an API. They help *structuring* your code - it's the basic encapsulation mechanism in [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Object literals are only one way to do this, you will find constructor functions as well, and you can mix the approaches. Check out the [various JavaScript design patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript), they are all based on objects.